# Accessing elements of an object in R

Tags: r, list

I have an object in R that returns the following structure when I apply str to it:

```
str(x)

dist [1:1] 
$ :List of 2
 ..$ mu   : num 759
 ..$ sigma: num 11.2
 ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "dist_normal" "dist_default"
@ vars: chr "Close"
```

I want to access the exact values of mu and sigma, but I cannot seem to find the correct way to do it... in the end I ended up using:

```
unlist(x)[1]
unlist(x)[2]
```

However, **which would be the correct way to access the original list structure? Could somebody help?**

As requested, the output of `dput(x)` is:

```
dput(x)

structure(list(structure(list(mu = 758.880005, sigma = 11.1895832820955), class = c("dist_normal", 
"dist_default"))), vars = "Close", class = c("distribution", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))
```

With this you should be able to reproduce the object as follows:

```
x <- structure(list(structure(list(mu = 758.880005, sigma = 11.1895832820955), class = c("dist_normal", 
"dist_default"))), vars = "Close", class = c("distribution", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))
```

Just for your information I have loaded the package `fpp3` for time series to handle these objects.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your list `x` using `dput(x)` to solve what you asked.

Comment: `x[['mu']]` doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have updated the answer with the output of dput(). Does this help? Can you reconstruct the entire object from that output? Could I perhaps ask how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is operators `$` and `[[` to extract the nested value by symbol name or character name, respectively. These operators must be used multiple times sequentially in case the list is nested:

```r
x <- structure(list(structure(list(mu = 758.880005, sigma = 11.1895832820955), class = c("dist_normal",  "dist_default"))), vars = "Close", class = c("distribution",  "vctrs_vctr", "list"))

x[[1]]$mu
#> [1] 758.88
```

Comment: Please provide the data using `dput(x)` in the question.

Comment: The output of dput:
`structure(list(structure(list(mu = 758.880005, sigma = 11.1895832820955), class = c("dist_normal", 
"dist_default"))), vars = "Close", class = c("distribution", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))`

Does this help? Or do you need something more? Thanks again.

Comment: Then do `x[[1]]$mu` This is a list with only one element

Comment: I tried that. Doing `x[[1]]$mu` yields `NULL`. The only thing that has worked so far for me is using `x2 <- unlist(x)` and then calling `x2[["mu"]]`, but there has to be a way to do it with the original object.

Comment: Then your `x` is different than the x produced by `dput`

Comment: I am curious, because I have copied the output of dput I shared here, assigned it to a variable and `x` and then run `x[[1]]$mu` and it is still returning NULL.

Did you successfully try it?

If so, could you share all your lines of code so that I could copy/paste and see if it works?

Many, many thanks.

Best,

Juan

Comment: @jj_coder I revised my answer

Comment: Hello. Found the problem. Loading the different tidyverse packages somehow overwrites the behavior of the `$` and the `[[` operators.

It is for this reason that I was getting a null. I know am able to access the elements of the list as you suggested and as I was trying to.

Thanks a lot for having taken the time to help me with this. This community is gold.

I also learnt about `dput()`, which I find extremely useful.

Best